# phpstorm wrong method declaration with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpstorm

I'm using phpstorm 8.0.3 (build 12 February) to build a Laravel 4.2 application. I'm also using the [_ide_helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) by Barry Heuvel.

I get an error when declaring a method with the same name as an Eloquent method. To be more clear, here is some example code:

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent{}

class OtherClass {

    public function update($first, $second, $third){
        //do some stuff
        return true;
    }

    public function check(){
        $item = SomeModel::findOrFail('1');
        $item->update([
            'name'  =>  'my name',
            'attribute' =>  'some attribute'
        ]);
        return "here's the problem!";
    }
}
```

In this code `item->update([...` gets highlighted red with the error message  **Required Parameter $second missing...** and if i use **"go to declaration"** on that piece of code instead of going to the declaration of the **update** method of Eloquent it goes to the the one declared on top.

Is anyone else getting this error? Have you found a fix? I'm not sure if its a problem of PhpStorm, my code or the ide_helper...

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I think I found the origin of the problem thanks to the comment by LazyOne.
In the declaration of **findOrFail** the PHPDoc reads: `@return \Illuminate\Support\Collection|static`.  When changed to `@return \Illuminate\Support\Collection\static' or simply without the static, the error isn't shown. Is PHPStorm nor reading the docstring properly or is the format incorrect?

Comment: It looks like IDE fails to detect correct type of `$item` most likely due to the way how `SomeModel::findOrFail()` works/declared -- it thinks that it is an instance of `OtherClass`. Proposed solution is to give a proper type hint via PHPDoc comment, e.g. `/** @var SomeModel $item */` before `$item = ...` line. P.S. I'm not Laravel user myself.

Comment: Thanks! Thats a good a patch, it fixes the error. but its still pretty annoying having to write that PHPDoc over each findOrFail, because I have many of them. Hope someone has a global solution. thanks again!

Comment: Use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper Provide `phpCode` for `PhpStorm`.

Comment: As I wrote in the beginning of the message, I am using the ide-helper. It has to do with @return declaration in the PHPDoc.